# error: undefined reference to class::method (main, header file, source code)

Tags: c++

Source File:

```
#include "WeatherForecaster.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


WeatherForecaster::WeatherForecaster(string d, string fd, int h, int l, int hum,int avgw, string avgwd, int maxw, string maxwd, double p){

string day=d;
string forecastDay=fd;
int highTemp=h;
int lowTemp =l;
int humidity=hum;
int avgWind= avgw;
string avgWindDir=avgwd;
int maxWind=maxw;
string maxWindDir= maxwd;
double recip=p;
 }
 WeatherForecaster::WeatherForecaster(){

 //dtor
 }
 void AddDaytoData(ForecastDay){
 }
```

Header File:

```
 #ifndef WEATHERFORECASTER_H
#define WEATHERFORECASTER_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 struct ForecastDay{
 std::string day;
 std::string forecastDay;
 int highTemp;
 int lowTemp;
 int humidity;
 int avgWind;
 std::string avgWindDir;
 int maxWind;
 std::string maxWindDir;
 double precip;

};

class WeatherForecaster

{

 public:

    WeatherForecaster(string, string, int, int,
    int,int, string, int, string , double );
    WeatherForecaster();
    void addDayToData(ForecastDay);
    void printDaysInData(); //prints the unique dates in the data
    void printForecastForDay(std::string);
    void printFourDayForecast(std::string);
    double calculateTotalPrecipitation();
    void printLastDayItRained();
    void printLastDayAboveTemperature(int); 
    void printTemperatureForecastDifference(std::string);
    void printPredictedVsActualRainfall(int); 
    std::string getFirstDayInData();
    std::string getLastDayInData();

 protected:
 private:
    int arrayLength;
    int index;
    ForecastDay yearData[984]; //data for each day
};

#endif // WEATHERFORECASTER_H
```

ERROR: My error happens when I declare try to reach a function in my source file after declaring an instance of the class Weather Function.

ex:

```
 WeatherForecaster wf;
 wf.AddDayToData();
//undefined reference to 'WeatherForecaster::AddDaytoData'
```

I am not entirely sure where the lack of referencing is happening, also I have the header included in main, as well as all other relevant additions.

Edit: I added a function as an example

Comment: I don't see this function declared in your class !

Comment: Wait, what? In order to be able to reference some function like this, you'll need to have it declared in your class.

Comment: I left it out just for brevity for readers. I am certain the function has no errors.

Comment: So you have all irrelevant code except the one that has error !

Comment: @grilam14, lol, you can't do this as this function is probably the cause of your problem. Also, _it's not declared_ in the declaration of your class. You can't have just missed it.

Comment: wf.AddDayToData(); Is missing an arg

Comment: I didn't think I needed an argument since I have public variables. And class resolution? ONE MORE EDIT: I do have the ForecastDay in the main code on Codeblocks

Comment: @grilam14, but you've declared your function so that it has one argument.

Comment: I added it, and now have error: expected primary expression before ')' token

Comment: @grilam14, you seem to have created multiple accounts in attempt to solve the problem. There exist at least three [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40055853/4354477) involving the same code and similar issues. Please don't do this as you're thus polluting SO with low-quality questions and potentially duplicate accounts.

Comment: @ForceBru My earlier post had 2 different problems that all ended up being the result of the solution, which we now have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cpp file you need to scope your member function definition

```
WeatherForecaster::AddDayToData(ForecastDay)
```

instead of

```
AddDayToData(ForecastDay)
```

Also in your call you must pass an argument since it's not optional

Comment: OH MY GOD THANK YOU. That was it.