# How do I get this constructor to work?

Tags: c++

I am stuck on how to make the constructor inside of the header class. I know that is why I can't call some methods. I really don't know what to do, I am trying to replicate how our teacher taught us, but it doesn't seem to be working too well as you can see. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Main.cpp File

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "WeatherForecaster.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open("boulderData.txt");
    int counter = 0;
    ForecastDay yearData[984];
    if(ifs.fail()){
        cout<<"File failed to open."<<endl;
    }else{
        string line;

        while(getline(ifs, line, '\n')){
            stringstream ss;
            ss<<line;
            string date1;
            string date2;
            getline(ss, date1, ',');
            getline(ss, date2, ',');

                string item;
                yearData[counter].day = date1;

                yearData[counter].forecastDay = date2;

                getline(ss, item, ',');
                size_t found = item.find(":");
                string s;
                s = item.substr(found+1, item.length()-1);
                yearData[counter].highTemp = stoi(s);

                getline(ss, item, ',');
                found = item.find(":");
                s = item.substr(found+1, item.length()-1);

                yearData[counter].lowTemp = stoi(s);

                getline(ss, item, ',');
                yearData[counter].humidity = stoi(item);

                getline(ss, item, ',');
                yearData[counter].avgWind = stoi(item);

                getline(ss, item, ',');
                yearData[counter].avgWindDir = item;

                getline(ss, item, ',');
                yearData[counter].maxWind = stoi(item);

                getline(ss, item, ',');
                yearData[counter].maxWindDir = item;

                getline(ss, item, ',');
                yearData[counter].precip = stod(item);

                counter++;
        }


    }

    WeatherForecaster wf;
    ForecastDay fd;


   // wf.printLastDayItRained(fd);

    double totalRain = wf.calculateTotalPrecipitation();
    cout << "Total rainfall: " << totalRain << endl;

    /*cout<< "Enter a date:" << endl;
    string date;
    getline(cin, date);
    wf.printForecastForDay(date);*/
}
```

WeatherForecast Header File

```
#ifndef WEATHERFORECASTER_H
#define WEATHERFORECASTER_H

#include <iostream>


struct ForecastDay{
    std::string day;
    std::string forecastDay;
    int highTemp;
    int lowTemp;
    int humidity;
    int avgWind;
    std::string avgWindDir;
    int maxWind;
    std::string maxWindDir;
    double precip;

};


class WeatherForecaster
{
    public:
        WeatherForecaster();
        ~WeatherForecaster();
        void addDayToData(ForecastDay);
        void printDaysInData();
        void printForecastForDay(std::string);
        void printFourDayForecast(std::string);
        double calculateTotalPrecipitation();
        void printLastDayItRained();
        void printLastDayAboveTemperature(int);
        void printTemperatureForecastDifference(std::string);
        void printPredictedVsActualRainfall(int);
        std::string getFirstDayInData();
        std::string getLastDayInData();
    protected:

    private:
        int arrayLength = 984;
        int index;
        ForecastDay yearData[984];
};

#endif // WEATHERFORECASTER_H
```

WeatherForecast.cpp Error: prototype for WeatherForecast::WeatherForecast

```
#include "WeatherForecaster.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

WeatherForecaster::WeatherForecaster(string d, string fd, int ht, int lt, int h, int aw, string awd, int mw, string mwd, double p){
    ForecastDay::day = d;
    ForecastDay::forecastDay = fd;
    ForecastDay::highTemp = ht;
    ForecastDay::lowTemp = lt;
    ForecastDay::humidity = h;
    ForecastDay::avgWind = aw;
    ForecastDay::avgWindDir = awd;
    ForecastDay::maxWind = mw;
    ForecastDay::maxWindDir = mwd;
    ForecastDay::precip = p;

}

WeatherForecaster::~WeatherForecaster(){

}

/*void addDayToData(ForecastDay yearData[]) {

    for(int i = 0; i < 984; i++) {
        if()
    }
}*/

void printDaysInData(ForecastDay yearData[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 984; i++) {
        if(yearData[i].day == yearData[i].forecastDay) {
            cout << yearData[i].day << endl;
        }
    }
}
void printForecastForDay(ForecastDay yearData[], string date) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 984; i++) {
        if(date == yearData[i].day && date == yearData[i].forecastDay)
            cout << "" << endl;
            cout << "Forecast for " << yearData[i].day << ": " << endl;
            cout << "H: " << yearData[i].highTemp << endl;
            cout << "L: " << yearData[i].lowTemp << endl;
            cout << "Humidity: " << yearData[i].humidity << endl;
            cout << "Avg Wind: " << yearData[i].avgWind << endl;
            cout << "Avg Wind Direction: " << yearData[i].avgWindDir << endl;
            cout << "Max Wind: " << yearData[i].maxWind << endl;
            cout << "Max Wind Direction: " << yearData[i].maxWindDir << endl;
            cout << "Precipitation: " << yearData[i].precip << endl;
    }
}
void printFourDayForecast(string) {

}
double calculateTotalPrecipitation(ForecastDay yearData[]) {
    double totalRain = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 984; i++) {
        totalRain = totalRain + yearData[i].precip;
    }
    return totalRain;
}
void printLastDayItRained(ForecastDay yearData[]) {
    string lastRained;
    for(int i = 0; i < 984; i++) {
        if(yearData[i].precip > 0) {
            lastRained = yearData[i].day;
            cout << lastRained << endl;
        }
    }
}

void printLastDayAboveTemperature(ForecastDay yearData[], int avgTemp) {
    string lastTemp;
    for(int i = 0; i < 984; i++) {
        if(yearData[i].day == yearData[i].forecastDay) {
            if(yearData[i].highTemp > avgTemp) {
                lastTemp = yearData[i].day;

            }
        }
    }
    cout << lastTemp << endl;
}

void printTemperatureForecastDifference(ForecastDay yearData[], string date) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 984; i++) {
        if(yearData[i].forecastDay == date) {
            cout << "Forecast for " << yearData[i].forecastDay << " issued on " << yearData[i].day << endl;
            cout << "H: " << yearData[i].highTemp << endl;
            cout << "L: " << yearData[i].lowTemp << endl;

        }

        if(yearData[i].forecastDay == date && yearData[i].day == date) {
            cout << "Actual forecast for " << yearData[i].day << endl;
            cout << "H: " << yearData[i].highTemp << endl;
            cout << "L: " << yearData[i].lowTemp << endl;
        }
    }

}
void printPredictedVsActualRainfall(int) {


}
string getFirstDayInData(ForecastDay yearData[]) {
    string date;
    for(int i = 0; i < 984; i++) {
        if(yearData[i].day == yearData[i].forecastDay) {
            date = yearData[i].day;
        }
    }
    return date;
}
string getLastDayInData(ForecastDay yearData[]) {
    string date;
    string currentDate;
    for(int i = 0; i < 984; i++) {
        if(yearData[i].day == yearData[i].forecastDay) {
            date = yearData[i].day;
        }
    }

    return date;

}
```

Comment: This very same question was [asked already here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40055028/need-help-identifying-issue-with-source-code-c-header-struct-class-complica).

Comment: What am I doing wrong from what you explained there?  I feel like I'm making the constructor the right way.

Comment: Please read the comments on that thread.  Where is the constructor declared like this? `WeatherForecaster(string d, string fd, int ht, int lt, int h, int aw, string awd, int mw, string mwd, double p);`?  You can't just make up functions that don't exist.  All you have declared is a constructor that takes no arguments.

Comment: The constructor you have defined in the cpp file is not the one declared in the header, and not the one you use in `main`. It *is* possible to have more than one constructor, but you have to be consistent with the class declaration.

Comment: Also, `ForecastDay::day = d;` is not the way to assign a value in the constructor. You use `yearData[i].day` in other places, so why not everywhere?

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to get this class working with **one** member variable and add all the others once that is working?

Comment: @PlagueKail -- Try to [fix this error](http://ideone.com/axacZL).  That is basically what your entire issue boils down to.  If you don't understand how to fix the error in the code at the link, then you're not going to understand how to even start addressing the problem you have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing all the irrelevant noise here seems to be (one of) your problem(s):

```
class WeatherForecaster
{
    public:
        // you declare a constructor that does not take any variables
        WeatherForecaster();

    // ...
};
```

Does the definition match?

```
// you define a constructor that takes three and a half million variables!!!
WeatherForecaster::WeatherForecaster(string d, string fd, int ht, int lt, int h, int aw, string awd, int mw, string mwd, double p){

    // ...    
}
```

You need to get your constructor declarations and definitions to match each other and how you intend to construct objects of this class.